# Swift 3, RxAlamofire and mapping to custom object

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire, rx-swift

I created simple project to check libraries like RxAlamofire and AlamofireObjectMapper. I have simple `ApiService` with one endpoint where is `PHP` script which works properly and returns `JSON`. I want call to `recipeURL` and I use `flatMap` operator to get response and provide it into `Mapper` where I should get `Recipe` object. How I can to do that?

Or is there other way?

```
class ApiService:  ApiDelegate{
    let recipeURL = "http://example.com/test/info.php"

    func getRecipeDetails() -> Observable<Recipe> {
        return request(.get, recipeURL)
            .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .flatMap({ request -> Observable<Recipe> in
                let json = ""//request.??????????? How to get JSON response?
                guard let recipe: Recipe = Mapper<Recipe>().map(JSONObject: json) else {
                    return Observable.error(ApiError(message: "ObjectMapper can't mapping", code: 422))
                }
            return Observable.just(recipe)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `RxAlamofire`'s readme, it seems a method `json(_:_:)` exists in the library.

Typically, you'd rather use `map` instead of `flatMap` to transform the returned data to another format. `flatMap` would be useful if you needed to subscribe to a new observable (for example, doing a second request using part of the result from the first one).

```
 return json(.get, recipeURL)
   .map { json -> Recipe in
     guard let recipe = Mapper<Recipe>().map(JSONObject: json) else {
       throw ApiError(message: "ObjectMapper can't mapping", code: 422)
     }
     return recipe
   }
```